# Linux - reasons for SIGSTOP and how to deal with it?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a Python script which is running bash scripts. I need to be able to kill the bash script if it seems to be infinite and it also has to be run in chroot jail because the script might be dangerous. I run it with `psutil.Popen()` and leave it running for two seconds. If it does not end naturally, I send `SIGKILL` to it and all of its possible children.

The problem is that if I kill one script due to overtime execution and run another one,  the main (Python) script receives a `SIGSTOP`. On my local machine, I made a really stupid solution: the Python script wrote its PID to a file at startup and then I run another script, which was sending `SIGCONT` every second to the PID which was stored in the file. This has two problems: it is really stupid, but even worse is that it refuses to work on the server - `SIGCONT` just does nothing there.

The sequence is: Python script runs a bash script responsive for the jail and that bash script runs the possibly dangerous and/or infinite script. This script might have some children as well.

The relevant parts of the codes:

**Main python script**

```
    p = psutil.Popen(["bash", mode, script_path, self.TESTENV_ROOT])
    start = time.time()

    while True:
        if p.status() == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
            # process ended naturally
            duration = time.time() - start
            self.stdout.write("Script finished, execution time: {}s".format(duration))
            break

        if time.time() > start + run_limit:
            children = p.children(recursive=True)
            for child in children:
                child.kill()
            p.kill()
            duration = None
            self.stdout.write("Script exceeded maximum time ({}s) and was killed.".format(run_limit))
            break

        time.sleep(0.01)

    os.kill(os.getpid(), 17)  # SIGCHLD
    return duration
```

**Running script in chroot** ($1 is the script to be run in the chroot jail, $2 is the jail path)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# copy script to chroot environment
cp "$1" "$2/prepare.sh"

# run script
chmod u+x "$2/prepare.sh"
echo './prepare.sh' | chroot "$2"
rm "$2/prepare.sh"
```

**Example prepare.sh script**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo asdf > file
```

I spent some time trying to solve the issue. I found out that this script (which is not using chroot jail to run bash scripts) is working perfectly:

```
import psutil
import os
import time

while True:
    if os.path.exists("infinite.sh"):
        p = psutil.Popen(["bash","infinite.sh"])
        start = time.time()

        while True:
            if p.status() == psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
                # process ended naturally
                break

            if time.time() > start + 2:
                # process needs too much time and has to be killed
                children = p.children(recursive=True)
                for child in children:
                    child.kill()

                p.kill()
                break

        os.remove("infinite.sh")
        os.kill(os.getpid(), 17)
```

My questions are:

- Why am I receiving `SIGSTOP`s? Is it due to the chroot jail?
- Is there any better way of hadling my problem than by running the "waking up" script?

Thanks for your ideas.

**EDIT:** I found out that I am sigstopped at the moment I run the first script after I killed an overtime one. No matter if I use `os.system` or `psutil.Popen`.

**EDIT2:** I did even more investigation and the critical line is `echo './prepare.sh' | chroot "$2"` in the bash script controlling the chroot jail. The question now is, what the hell is wrong with it?

**EDIT3:** [This](http://linux-kernel.vger.kernel.narkive.com/v8Jhd6WB/fork-sh-hello-microbenchmark-performance-in-chroot) might be a related problem, if it helps someone.

Comment: Can you post this `prepare.sh` script?

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution. The problem really was on the chroot line in the bash script:

```
echo './prepare.sh' | chroot "$2"
```

This appears to be incorrect for some reason. The correct way to run a command in chroot is:

```
chroot chroot_path shell -c command
```

So for example:

```
chroot '/home/chroot_jail' '/bin/sh' -c 'rm -rf /'
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're running this on Mac OS and not Linux. Why? You're sending signal `17` to your main python process instead of using:

```
import signal
signal.SIGCHLD
```

I believe you have a handler for signal `17` which is supposed to respawn the jailed process in response to this signal.
But `signal.SIGCHLD == 17` on Linux and `signal.SIGCHLD == 20` on Mac OS.

Now the answer for your question is:
**`signal.SIGSTOP == 17` on Mac OS**.
Yes, your process sends `SIGSTOP` to itself with `os.kill(os.getpid(), 17)`
[Mac OS signal man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html)

**EDIT:**
Actually it can also happen on Linux since [Linux signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) says that POSIX standard allows signal `17` to be either `SIGUSR2`, `SIGCHLD` or `SIGSTOP`. Therefore I strongly recommend using constants from `signal` module of the standard library instead of hardcoded signal numbers.

Comment: Do you really think that I do not know which system I am using?
I commented out the SIGCHLD line, and, no surprise, the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Have you tried using constants from `signal` library instead of hardcoded numbers? Was the effect the same? Did I insult you? I really didn't want to. Making simple mistakes is part of our (programmer's) life. It just happens all the time and there's no need to be sorry about it. Maybe it's not Mac OS in your case but still you're sending a singal number 17 and then your process receives SIGSTOP. There's too much of coincidence. Sorry. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Well, it sounds quite weird from you if you think that I could mix up Linux and Mac OS, but never mind... :)
I looked at `signal.SIGCHLD` and went to the definition in the `signals` library. I found this line:
`SIGCHLD = 17`
So...any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe, if you think there could be some relevant piece of code which I did not post, just ask for it. The problem is that the application is quite huge and it is impossible to post the whole code.

Comment: And for your convenience: `kill -l` says that `SIGCHLD` is 17, `SIGCONT` is 18 and `SIGSTOP` is 19.

Comment: See my edit. Is it also `17` inside chroot jail? I mean, you can have a different (and sometimes non-standard) distro under chroot than your host system.

Comment: The chroot jail is copied from my system so it would be super weird. I double checked it anyway and 17 is really `SIGCHLD`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: If that's the case then it would really be super weird. But not as weird as `SIGSTOP` magically popping up from nowhere. Please try switching to constants from `signal` module, just to make sure.

Comment: Great, you finally got my point :). I replaced that damned 17 with `signal.SIGCHLD` and guess what, behavior is still the same. I searched my whole project for all signals and there are no more. I guess Linux just hates me.

Comment: I did some more investigation and found out that I am sigstopped when I run the first script after I killed an overtime script, no matter if I use `os.system()` or `psutil.Popen()`. `os.system` unfortunately has no Python code available so I cannot add debugging prints there. I still have no idea what to do. Do you have any?

Comment: And I did even more investigation and the critical line is this one: `echo './prepare.sh' | chroot "$2"`. The question now is, what the hell is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a little bit older but I believe I know the cause of your problem (had a similar issue):

From [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) it says:

> Linux supports the standard signals listed below. [...] First the signals described in the original POSIX.1-1990 standard.
>
> ```
>   Signal     Value     Action   Comment
>    ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
>                                  or death of controlling process
>    SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
>    SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
>    SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
>    SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
>    SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating-point exception
>    SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
>    SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
>    SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
>                                  readers; see pipe(7)
>    SIGALRM      14       Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
>    SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
>    SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
>    SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
>    SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
>    SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
>    SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
>    SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at terminal
>    SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process
>    SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Terminal output for background process
> ```

It shows, that a process (per default action) also gets stopped when it receives the SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN, or SIGTTOU signals.

This [page](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux) explains that:

> [SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU] are signals that are sent to background processes that they attempt to read from (SIGTTIN) or write to (SIGTTOU) their controlling
>   terminal (or tty).
>   
> ...
>   [...] changing terminal settings [from a background process] does cause SIGTTOU to be sent

I used `sudo strace -tt -o [trace_output_file] -p [pid]` to see which signal triggered the stopping of my process.

How to solve the Problem? I sadly cannot get your reduced example to work: How does your infinite.sh looks like? Why are you removing it during execution?
I suggest redirecting stdin and stdout. Have you tried the following?

```
from subprocess import DEVNULL
p = psutil.Popen(["bash", mode, script_path, self.TESTENV_ROOT],
                 stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, STDIN=DEVNULL)
```

You can of course also use subprocess.PIPE to handle the output in your Python code or simply redirect to a file. I am not sure how to handle unauthorized attempts to modify the tty settings.